# Не получается подключить скрипт

Tags: javascript, node.js

В файле пишу так:

```
module.exports.b2World = b2World;
```

файл называется:

```
D:\OpenServer\domains\td\lib\box2d\dynamics\b2World.js
```

Подключать пытаюсь так:

```
        this.express = require('express');
        this.app = this.express();

        var b2World = require('../../lib/box2d/dynamics/b2World');

        var server = require('http').createServer(function (req:any, res:any) {
        });
        server.listen(Server.Config.SERVER_SETTING.SOCKET_PORT);
        this.network = new Network(server);
```

Не работает только это подключение

```
 var b2World = require('../../lib/box2d/dynamics/b2World');
```

Ошибка:

> Error: Cannot find module '../../lib/box2d/dynamics/b2World'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Core.initialize (D:\OpenServer\domains\td\server.js:562:27)
>       at new Core (D:\OpenServer\domains\td\server.js:557:18)
>       at Object. (D:\OpenServer\domains\td\server.js:572:12)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:458:32)

Comment: Вместо `../../` должно быть `./`

Comment: Вы бы определились: у вас не подключается файл или все-таки подключается, но выдает `ReferenceError`

Comment: Для каждой отдельной проблемы - отдельный вопрос!

Comment: prototype.js можно подключить как то через npm?

Comment: Если он есть в репозитории npm - то можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При разрешении пути к модулю node.js использует каталог текущего файла (в котором производится подключение) как базовый.

Судя по тексту ошибки, подключение вы проводите в файле:

```
D:\OpenServer\domains\td\server.js
```

Если ваша библиотека лежит в

```
D:\OpenServer\domains\td\lib\box2d\dynamics\b2World.js
```

то инструкция подключения должна иметь вид:

```
var b2World = require('./lib/box2d/dynamics/b2World');
```

Comment: подключить помогло спасибо, только 2-я проблема вылезла =)